# I keep getting a logic error trying to use the try-catch

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

I am learning python using a book, one of the excersises is ;
Exercise 3: Write a program to prompt for a score between 0.0 and
1.0. If the score is out of range, print an error message. If the score is
between 0.0 and 1.0, print a grade using the following table:
Score Grade >= 0.9 A, >= 0.8 B, >= 0.7 C, >= 0.6 D, < 0.6 F

I came up with the following;

```
inp = input('enter score: ')
try:
    float(inp >= 0.00) and float(inp <= 1.00)
    if inp >= 0.90:
        grade = 'A'
    elif inp >= 0.80:
        grade = 'B'
    elif inp >= 0.70:
        grade = 'C'
    elif inp >= 0.60:
        grade = 'D'
    elif inp < 0.60:
        grade = 'F'
    print('Grade: ',grade)
except: 
    print('bad score')
```

any input I input, regardless if it meets the conditions I set for the input or not comes out to the error message, "bad grade"
Im not sure what I did wrong here honestly.
Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: `float(inp >= 0.00) and float(inp <= 1.00)` is not doing anything. inp should instead be declared as `inp = float(input('enter score: '))` and grade is not set prior to being printed out therefore you should set the `grade = 'F'` before the try. besides that you don't really need a try except block you should instead have an `else` block for the final message printed or a try block around the input score.

Answer (score 0):

The only code inside a `try` should be the code that can potentially raise an exception you want to handle. You should never use a bare `except` like this --always handle specific exceptions, or at the very least `Exception`.

The only operation that can throw an exception here is attempting to convert the user input (which is a string) to a numeric type, which will throw a `ValueError`. You *can* also raise a `ValueError` if the value isn't between 0 and 1:

```py
try:
    score = float(input("enter score: "))
    if not (0.0 <= score <= 1.0):
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    print("please enter a decimal value between 0.0 and 1.0")

# Now do letter grade logic
```

With this try/except block, you can go one step further and wrap it in a loop that will keep asking the user for input until they enter a valid input:

```py
while True:
    try:
        score = float(input("enter score: "))
        if not (0.0 <= score <= 1.0):
            raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter a decimal value between 0.0 and 1.0")
```